# Adding onchange event to a telerik dropdownlist makes it static

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

I have a telerik dropdownlist which behaves normally, but once I add an onchange event which triggers a JS function, the dropdownlist becomes static.

Telerik DDL:

```
<%= Html.Telerik().DropDownList().Name("Week")
            .HtmlAttributes(new { @id = "Week", @style = "width:104px;" }).ClientEvents(events => events.OnChange("Week_onChange"))%>
```

JavaScript function:

```
function Week_onChange() {
    var link = '/Weeks/Week';
    week = $("#Week").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: link,
        data: { date: week },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result.message);
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert(result.message);
        }
    });
};
```

Here is how I populate the Week DDL:

```
$("#Week").data("tDropDownList").dataBind(weekArray);
$('#Week').data('tDropDownList').select(0);
```

Again, Week DDL acts perfectly fine if I dont have the "Week_onChange" event added.
Any help is much appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by static? Is there any JavaScript error in the console?

Comment: @XMR No JavaScript error. As soon as I add a client event to telerik ddl it becomes static, as it I am unable to view select values from the ddl. it behaves like its disabled. I even tried setting a default value after data binding, but that is not displayed either.

Comment: Not sure whats wrong. If you can provide a live URL with two DDLs (one with change handler and one without) so I can take a look.

Comment: @XMR how could I provide you a like URL? you know any online resource which does telerik demos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the "@id" from html attributes resolved this issue. Thanks! all